# ¿Cómo eliminar imagen de producto en la galería del producto en woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Pido su ayuda y mas experiencia.

Yo no quiero que la imagen de la galería de la tienda aparezca en la galería del producto. No se si me explico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que si uso css usando .clase {display:none;}

Pero no tengo una clase ni id a que aplicarle

Pero temo que si oculto la imagen de la tienda en la galería del producto esta también se va eliminar como imagen principal del producto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si me logro explicar. ¿O es imposible lo que quiero hacer?

De ante mano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la solución:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'remove_featured_image', 10, 2);
function remove_featured_image($html, $attachment_id ) {
    global $post, $product;
    $featured_image = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
    if ( $attachment_id == $featured_image )
       $html = '';
       return $html;
}
```